# Nginx not working with Laravel

Tags: nginx, php, configuration

I have a Webserver (a Droplet) at **DigitalOcean**. This Droplet runs on **Ubuntu 16.04**. I have install Laravel correctly in that I can use "*laravel new appname*" and "*php artisan ...*" inside the new folder.

I have installed **Nginx** as the Webserver of choice.

I have created the Laravel project in */var/www/folder1/appname/* and in the nginx server config file I have this:

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/appname**:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name mydomain.de www.mydomain.de
    root /var/www/folder1/appname/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$is_args$args;
    }

    # I have tried it with and without this part
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I have system linked this file to */etc/nginx/sites-enabled*.

When I go to *mydomain.de* all I see is either the default nginx page or the default apache page.

I "*chown'nd*"' everything below /var/www/ to my account and group.

When I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-laravel-application-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial and downloaded the Quickstart project from Github it worked.

Am I doing something wrong?

P.S. I am using php 7.1 now and was using 7.0 when I tried the tutorial. But I had to upgrade scince composer

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the default nginx page, it is not picking up the host header and thus using the default server block.

I noticed you are missing a semi-colon at the end of this line:

> server_name mydomain.de www.mydomain.de

If that is the case on your actual server, this would explain the issue. I believe the output of `nginx -t` would report an error.